# I need a way to score the lucene documents using term frequency only. Is there any flag that needs to be changed for this?

Tags: lucene

If i have two documents with D1 having term "lucene" twice and D2 having term "lucene" thrice. I want lucene to score D2 higher than D1. Note here that, D1 has only two words (i.e. lucene lucene) while D3 has 100 words out of which 3 words are lucene. Default lucene scoring model will score D1 higher than D2. I want to disable this mode and rank D2 higher than D1. That's my project requirement.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to implement a Similarity which does what you want.  You could implement directly on `Similarity`, but you'll probably find it's simpler to just copy `ClassicSimilarity` (`DefaultSimilarity`, before version 5.4), and stub out the things you don't want to impact your score (ie. return a constant).  For instance, here's a very simple implementation that would simply return the frequency of the terms in the query:

```java
import org.apache.lucene.index.FieldInvertState;
import org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.TFIDFSimilarity;
import org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef;

public class SimpleSimilarity extends TFIDFSimilarity {
//Comments describe briefly what these methods do in the *standard* implementation.
//Not what they do in this implementation (which, for most of them, is nothing at all)

  public SimpleSimilarity() {}

  //boosts results which match more query terms
  @Override
  public float coord(int overlap, int maxOverlap) {
    return 1f;
  }

  //constant per query, normalizes scores somewhat based on query
  @Override
  public float queryNorm(float sumOfSquaredWeights) {
    return 1f;
  }

  //Norms should be disabled when using this similarity
  //They are useless to it, and would just be wasted space.
  @Override
  public final long encodeNormValue(float f) {
    return 1L;
  }

  @Override
  public final float decodeNormValue(long norm) {
    return 1f;
  }

  //Weighs shorter fields more heavily
  @Override
  public float lengthNorm(FieldInvertState state) {
    return 1f;
  }

  //Higher frequency terms (more matches) scored higher
  @Override
  public float tf(float freq) {
    //return (float)Math.sqrt(freq);  The standard tf impl
    return freq;
  }

  //Scores closer matches higher when using a sloppy phrase query
  @Override
  public float sloppyFreq(int distance) {
    return 1.0f;
  }

  //ClassicSimilarity doesn't really do much with payloads.  This is unmodified
  @Override
  public float scorePayload(int doc, int start, int end, BytesRef payload) {
    return 1f;
  }

  //Weigh matches on rarer terms more heavily.
  @Override
  public float idf(long docFreq, long numDocs) {
    return 1f;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "SimpleSimilarity";
  }
}
```